# Process-wide VPN connection via openconnect

Tags: linux, vpn, linux-networking, automation

I'm using `openconnect` to connect to a remote endpoint and SSH onto the machine inside the remote network. The problem is, when I do create the connection, the machine I do it on is unresponsive for any other connection from its local network.

What I'm trying to achieve here is a kind of a deployment server which would have the knowledge of connecting to various remote servers and push files / do stuff remotely. The ideal solution would include me being able to do multiple VPN connections in parallel (for example, two different deploys to two totally different VPN networks).

Is any of this possible? If so, how?